# About .net core handler method routing

Tags: ajax, routes, handler, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.1

About .net core handler method routing
Calling PageModel's handler method with ajax.
At this time, please tell me how to set the routing for each handler method
I want to set in handler method units instead of page units

PagemodelName:IndexModel

handler method name:OnPostGetDataAsync

An example

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Index?handler=GetData',
```

I want to change to the following

```
url: '/test/Index?handler=GetData'
```

Please tell me how to implement to achieve this routing.
After adding the Route attribute, the following warning will be displayed, so I would like to implement it by a method other than adding the Route attribute（[Route("test")]）

RouteAttribute　cannot be applied to Razor pages.......

Comment: You can use `AddPageRoute` to specify an alternative route for a page: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing#friendly-routes

Comment: thank you for your answer. But what I want to do is AJAX routing, not per page. Changing the url here will also change the url of the page. It's the traditional way of adding Route Attribute to Action of controller. Only when calling AJAX.

Comment: The AddPageRoute method doesn't change the URL for the page. It creates an additional route that the page can be reached at.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
After rewriting as follows using AddPageRoute, options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("Index","test/Index");
When you display the Index page in your browser, the url of the page is also rewritten.
https://localhost/test/Index
When displaying in a browser, I want to display as follows.
https://localhost/Index
I want to add a test prefix only when calling with AJAX.